# Azure Media Services - Custom Transform set on client is Lost?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

My custom code to run Encoding, Indexing has been using a Custom Transform since last 6 months, and suddenly it is no longer able to execute the tasks as it is supposed to be, with respect to Encoding with defined resolution, analyzer preset and Indexing.

There haven't been any changes in the code or in my Media Services account.

When I checked with "Get Transform", the custom transform has no details.

```
Transform transform = await client.Transforms.GetAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, transformName);
if (transform == null)
{
TransformOutput[] outputs = new TransformOutput[]
{
  new TransformOutput
  {
      Preset = new BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset()
    {
         PresetName = EncoderNamedPreset.AdaptiveStreaming
    }
  },
  new TransformOutput(preset)
};
transform = await client.Transforms.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, transformName, outputs);
}
```

Are there any changes on Azure side which may have caused my custom transform settings to disappear?

Is there any way to recover previously set custom transform from your IAzureMediaServicesClient?

Comment: We would need your Azure Media Service account name, region name, and the Transform name in order to investigate. If you can't share these on this forum, please open a support ticket via Azure Portal.

Comment: Thanks! Realized after investigation that it has got overridden in one of the test cycle. Is there any way to retrieve previous version of the Transform?

Comment: Yes, it may be possible. Please do open a support ticket with the details above, as well as the last approximate date/time/timestamp that you last submitted a Job with the Transform with its desired settings.